# Looking for the go code which does Kubernetes CreationTimestamp -> AGE

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm try to get the "AGE" column value from kubernetes api as in the command output

```
> kubectl get po
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-56c75d774d-d7zx8   1/1     Running   1          29d
nfs-client-provisioner-5cd984898b-s8fzh     1/1     Running   1          13d
```

```
func getVolumes() VolumesOutput {

    userNamespace := "test"
    listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
        Limit: 100,
    }

    volumeList, err := ClientSet.CoreV1().PersistentVolumeClaims(userNamespace).List(listOptions)

    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }
    volumeItems := volumeList.Items

    volumes := make([]Volume, 0)
    if len(volumeItems) > 0 {
        for _, volumeItem := range volumeItems {
            quant := volumeItem.Spec.Resources.Requests[v1.ResourceStorage]
            volume := Volume{
                Name: volumeItem.Name,
                Capacity: quant.String(),
                Age:      volumeItem.ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp.String(),
                UserID:   UserID,
            }
            volumes = append(volumes, volume)

        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println("no volumes found")
    }
    log.Println(volumes)

    vol := VolumesOutput{
        Volumes: volumes,
    }

    return vol
}
```

So I can get the CreationTimestamp in

```
Age:      volumeItem.ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp.String(),
```

I tried to find the code that does the conversion from time to AGE couldn't find it in kubernetes github repo..

I like to convert it as the same as in kubectl does. So please give me an example and also point to the correct line that does it on repo.

Comment: Not 100% sure (that's why I don't answer and just comment) but my guess is it is `now - creationTimestamp` passed to `HumanDuration()` from here: `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/duration`.

Comment: @blami, That is the one I'm looking for. !!.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As the [`ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ObjectMeta) is of  type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) , you can simply use [`Time.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub) to get the difference between the current time and the creation timestamp which will you give you the age of the resource.

You can use `time.Now()` to get the current timestamp.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    currentTime := time.Now()
    creationTime := currentTime.Add(time.Hour * 12)
    
    diff := creationTime.Sub(currentTime)
    fmt.Println("Age:", diff)
}
```

Output:

```
Age: 12h0m0s
```

Note: The above is used for example purpose since the creation time would be generally before the current time.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm aware that it's a time.Time. kubectl is doing some formatting on that. ex. it doesn't show anything like "12h0m0s". depending on the difference it has a logic. sometimes it shows seconds sometimes it shows mins , days etc. That is why I have asked for that code snippet in k8s repo or where ever it's.